# Display and aggregate data with Logstash and Kibana

Tags: jenkins, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

I am currently trying to get log data from my Jenkinses and display dashboards in Kibana.

Infrastructure:
[image]

- I have multiple Jenkins instances running multiple different jobs.
- With Filebeat, each log line is sent to Kafka (logs from different jobs could get mixed up).
- Then my Logstash pipeline checks if there is an error message in the log and adds fields like: error.message:"C++ error." or error.id:"C++".
- An entry in Elasticsearch looks something like this:

```
"fields": {
    "agent.name": [
      "jenkins_one"
    ],
    "jenkins_job": [
      "My Job"
    ]
    "message": [
      "     [echo] [SOME_ERROR] 2023-08-25 22:18:29.145 [6652] [ERROR] [C++Assert] "
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-08-25T20:18:44.913Z"
    ],
    "error.type": [
      "Error"
    ],
    "error.message": [
      "C++ error appeared in the log."
    ],
    "error.id": [
      "C++"
    ],
    "build_number": [
      506
    ]
  }
```

The big problem now is that I do not know if the job has failed or not per record, because only the last log line of a job can tell me that.
So if it is the last log line, it will say something like: "Finished: FAILURE" and then I add the attribute build_failure:true to my Elasticsearch record, but only on that one.

I now want to create meaningful dashboards in Kibana like this:

- Which error causes the most failures per job or jenkins.

How can I group the elasticsearch entries in Kibana and check if my job failed. And then also identify the real error. Is this even possible?

Now that I had found no way to do this for me, I wrote an external Python program to aggregate the log lines. I then stored this data in a database and displayed it in Grafana.

But I think there should be a way to do this in Kibana itself.

Comment: Can't you use build number as the primary key for error messages and place a conditional sum on error messages with only builds with a fail log existing on those build numbers? Might need to add another record for fail/success parsing onto ES. I am no expert on ES but I suppose it would have caches for calculating those aggregate queries of yours to perform fast.

Comment: For me now there was no other way then adding a parent/child relation with join field type. Joins without that would not work...